# Is there a way of replicating abstract class approach with typescript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a function that returns an array type that has some custom methods, and that I can use in different parts of the application.

The idea here I believe is typically achieved with Abstract classes, where I define an Abstract class with a couple of abstract methods and every class that extends this class needs to implement those methods (in its own way).

I was wondering if I could achieve something similar using TypeScript interfaces.

The code bellow represents roughly what I'm trying to achieve:

1: Fetch some data from an API endpoint which I know that it will always be an array of objects and, depending on the API method that I call, these objects will have different aspect.

2: Since when calling the api I know the aspect of it, for example I know that /posts will return an array and each object in the array will have a property called name so whenever I call Posts[i].myCustomGetter() it will actually return the name property. However, I know when calling /posts2 then what I actually want is the Posts[i].myCustomGetter() to return the specialname property.

3: I want to be able to use Posts in different parts of my application. Always calling the myCustomGetter, without having to worry how exactly it is implemented.

```
import axios from 'axios'

interface Posts {
    [index: number]: Post
}

interface Post {
    // I know post will have a couple of properties
    // that will come from the Axios Response Data.
    // However, I want to add additional custom function
    // depending on where I use this interface
    myCustomGetter: () => string
}

export async function getPosts(): Promise<Posts> {
    return new Promise<Posts>((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
            .get<Posts>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((response) => {

                // is there a way to define here the
                // function declaration of myCustomGetter() ?
                // for example, for this api call, i want 
                // myCustomGetter to be something like
                // myCustomGetter() => { return thisPost.name }
                // and name is something that I know (because I know the api) that will exist

                resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })
    })
}
```

Apologies if I sound confusing, but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with a solution using a combination of an interface and class.

```
import axios from 'axios'

interface IPosts {
    items: any[]
    get(index: number): Post
}

interface Post {
    name: string
}

export class Posts implements IPosts {
    items: any[]

    constructor(items: any[]) {
        this.items = items
    }

    get(index: number): Post {
        const item = this.items[index]
        return {
            // I know that these type of post items have a prop named title.
            name: item.title,
        }
    }
}

export async function getPosts(): Promise<Posts> {
    return new Promise<Posts>((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(new Posts(response.data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })
    })
}
```

Now every time I want to access one of the Posts, for example position 0, I do something like:

```
getPosts()
    .then((Posts: Posts) => {
        console.log(Posts.get(0))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

And, if I want to make sure that one of my functions is expecting a class that implements the IPost, I make use of generic constraints in typescript:

```
function DoSomething<T extends Posts>(arg: T): void {
    console.log(arg.get(0))
}

getPosts()
    .then((Posts: Posts) => {
        DoSomething(Posts)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```